# Android Studio apk size weird issue

Tags: android-studio, build, apk, filesize

Ok so this is a weird one.

**STEP 1:** I'm making a new release for my app so I generate a signed apk from the current state of my git repository and it has a size of 29MB.

**STEP 2:** I checkout my repository at an earlier commit from 1 year ago. I generate another signed apk which results in a apk size of 21MB because the project had much less code back then.

**STEP 3:** Then I checkout to the current state of my repository as before and make another signed apk. This time the generated apk has a size of 24MB.

**Proguard is enabled in all scenarios I mentioned.**

So apk C is 5MB smaller than apk A, even though it is supposed to contain the same code.

This has been happening for a long time. I have updated Android Studio since and still happening. I'm practically "forced" to use this trick in order to upload a smaller apk file and it is really annoying to do this every time I make a new release.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: Have you cleared the build cache to make sure no outdated cached files are used in the build process?

Comment: That actually worked. I didn't think of doing that because I assumed a signed apk is built from scratch without using caches, hence the longer time to complete.